# Access Sharepoint List from Teams Tab created using Teams toolkit

Tags: sharepoint, teams-toolkit

I am currently using Graph APIs to connect to share point list from the Teams tab(NOT SPFX TAB) that I created using Teams Toolkit. I would like to know if it's possible to use REST API or PNP library to connect to Share point list items other than Graph API.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [Sharepoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph) in Teams Tab. Note that you need to update permission for Azure AD app and request for access token with proper permission with TeamsFx SDK to call Sharepoint REST API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please share any references or samples for the code to call REST API from TeamsFx.